# What is the best approach to make all the imports with in the service available across all dask workers?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I had a few questions around how to make the imports available across the Dask workers.
1) I see that using upload_file functionality you can make files available for workers . 
Other than this what are the other options to get this done?
2) If we include the upload_file for all the imports, For every service call in backend will it keep on uploading to workers ? will it get removed after the task is executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are lots of ways to do this, depending on how you are deploying dask.

A couple of examples:

- all workers have access to NFS, so put your code files there and include it in the python path
- workers are accessed via SSH, so use scp to copy your code to all worker machines
- you are deploying via docker/kubernetes, so include the code in the image
- you are deploying via dask-yarn: look up [conda-pack](https://yarn.dask.org/en/latest/environments.html#archiving-conda-environments-using-conda-pack)

upload_file puts the code into a temporary location which is on the worker's python path. The file will persist there until at least when the worker process ends, it will not be re-uploaded between tasks. It will be imported by the code as normal python modules (i.e., importing again will use the cached version). New workers that join after the upload_file command will not have a copy of the file.

Comment: got it Thanks alot for the clarification. In my case I am deploying dask to ECS cluster and trying to call my client from a flask application that resides outside the dask cluster. So for getting the import work your suggesting to deploy my flask service to the same dask cluster?

Comment: I didn't say that, it's up to you. Of the example, this falls most easily under amending the docker image. Your flask app can live anyway, depends on your other constraints.