# Setting worker packages in Dask, best practices

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, dask, dask-distributed

What is the best practice for installing packages on workers? I have seen suggested ways [here](https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/1200) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49327802/push-a-pure-python-module-to-dask-workers), but the Dask documentation does not discuss this issue.

Background: 
In my case, I am trying to use dask delayed (or futures) to parallelize a for loop which calls a function; this function operates on Pandas dataframes using Scipy.spatial. Each Dask worker would have to import the scipy package. I am unsure whether this is a bad way to parallelize this code, which would explain the relative lack of information about this issue. I can write up a minimal example if that would help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best approach to make all the imports with in the service available across all dask workers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60643162/what-is-the-best-approach-to-make-all-the-imports-with-in-the-service-available)

Comment: Thank you. I saw that as well, but I am relatively inexperienced with docker images and NFS. Using SCP would mean copying all of the scipy.spatial library I believe. I was wondering if there was a way to do this within Dask since it seems like a common use case.

Comment: Dask is not an environment manager. You could use conda-pack to distribute environments, or client.run() to call whatever system install commands on every worker if you wanted.

Comment: Ok that clears things up. Thank you!